# Import CSV data into MySQL

Tags: php, csv, import

Consider the following snippet CSV data from "NASDAQ.csv"

```
"Symbol,""Name"",""LastSale"",""MarketCap"",""ADR TSO"",""IPOyear"",""Sector"",""industry"",""Summary Quote"",";;
"FLWS,""1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc."",""2.9"",""81745200"",""n/a"",""1999"",""Consumer Services"",""Other Specialty Stores"",""http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/flws"",";;
"FCTY,""1st Century Bancshares, Inc"",""4"",""36172000"",""n/a"",""n/a"",""Finance"",""Major Banks"",""http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fcty"",";;
"FCCY,""1st Constitution Bancorp (NJ)"",""8.8999"",""44908895.4"",""n/a"",""n/a"",""Finance"",""Savings Institutions"",""http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fccy"",";;
```

I'm trying to import Symbol, Sector, and Industry into a MySQL table with corresponding fields:

```
$path = "NASDAQ.csv";
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $row++;
    $entries[] = $data ;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}

foreach ($entries as $line) {
  db_query("
     INSERT INTO us_stocks (symbol, name, sector, industry) 
     VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
     $line[0], $line[1], $line[6], $line[7]
  );
}
```

The result, however, is not what I expected. In the database, only the Symbol field gets filled, and not even correctly:

```
symbol      name  sector  industry
----------------------------------
Symbol,"Na
FLWS,"1-80
FCTY,"1st
FCCY,"1st
```

What am I doing wrong?

[edit]

If I print_r($entries), the output looks like

```
Array (
  [0] => Array(
    [0] => Symbol,"Name","LastSale","MarketCap","ADR TSO","IPOyear","Sector","industry","Summary Quote",;;
  )
  [1] => Array(
    [0] => FLWS,"1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc.","2.9","81745200","n/a","1999","Consumer Services","Other Specialty Stores","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/flws",;;
  )
  [2] => Array(
    [0] => FCTY,"1st Century Bancshares, Inc","4","36172000","n/a","n/a","Finance","Major Banks","http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fcty",;;
  )
)
```

[edit2]

I have deleted the first line of the CSV, as suggested. I now have a very quick and dirty way of almost accomplishing what I want. Basically, the thing messes up whenever there's a company name with ", Inc" in it. So I just "glue" it to the name above: $data[1] = $data[1] . $data[2]:

```
$path = "NASDAQ.csv";
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";;")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($row < 100) {
      $row++;
      $data = explode(',', $data[0]);
      if (substr($data[2], 0, 1) == ' ') {
        $data[1] = $data[1] . $data[2];
        unset($data[2]);
      }
      $entries[] = $data ;
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

A print_r($entries) now gives:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => FLWS
        [1] => "1-800 FLOWERS.COM Inc."
        [3] => "2.9"
        [4] => "81745200"
        [5] => "n/a"
        [6] => "1999"
        [7] => "Consumer Services"
        [8] => "Other Specialty Stores"
        [9] => "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/flws"
        [10] => 
    )
```

Final problem: I don't know how to renumber the keys. So 3 into 2, 4 into 3, etc. so that the output looks like:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => FLWS
        [1] => "1-800 FLOWERS.COM Inc."
        [2] => "2.9"
        [3] => "81745200"
        [4] => "n/a"
        [5] => "1999"
        [6] => "Consumer Services"
        [7] => "Other Specialty Stores"
        [8] => "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/flws"
        [9] => 
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd guess that it has to do with double-double quotes used in your CSV file.  The fourth argument of `fgetcsv()` (`$enclosure`) could be set to `"\"\""` to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the data isn't "truely" CSV.

"FLWS,""1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc."",""2.9"", 
should be :
"FLWS","1-800 FLOWERS.COM, INC.","2.9" - The quotes should wrap the individual fields with commas seperating each field.  Usually numeric fields are not wrapped.

Depending on how you load the data, comma's in the data *may* confuse it.  (i.e. the FLOWERS.COM, INC"

By the way - if it's really CSV - look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Well, it sure isn't the best csv file I ever saw...but it's whats available on nasday.com and I couldn't find any other source for importing the ticker symbols of all US stocks (I have other csv's like AMEX, NYSE, from the same website). Couldn't I just strip all " and ' from all fields?

Comment: The 1st line must have a typo on it, as theres no separator between Symbol and Name outside the quotes.  I'd just do a replacement of all "" with " (change or tr 2 x quotes to 1 x quote) and use load data infile skipping the 1st line, and specifying the columns to load.. I *guarantee* if you go with load data infile, your inserts will be monsterously fast.

Comment: Probably, but for now, I think hacking something together in php works faster for me...almost there btw :) Please have a look at my final question - how to renumber keys - if you have time.

Comment: http://samuelkerr.com/?page_id=287 has an example of the load data infile thing - just fyi.   On the other question, look at array_values and array_keys - I'm sure they're what you're after.

Comment: Very quick and dirty, I used $data = array_merge(array(), $data); to reindex. Problem solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As Crontab said, probably it's a problem with quotes. Try:

```
foreach ($entries as $line) {

  // Escape (see mysql_real_escape_string too) and remove double quotes
  foreach ($line as $k => $v) $line[$k] = mysql_escape_string(trim($v, '"'));

  // Rebuild array
  $line = array_values($line);

  db_query("
    INSERT INTO us_stocks (symbol, name, sector, industry) 
    VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
    $line[0], $line[1], $line[6], $line[7]
 );

}
```

*PS: I don't know if you already escape strings in `db_query()`.*

Comment: I already do. However, it's not working. And neither is your code. It now just reads FLWS,\"1-8 etc. because of double escaping. Perhaps it would be better to just use regex to remove all single and double quotes from each $data line?

Comment: `trim($v, '"')` removes single or multiple double quotes from the beginning and end of the string. So, I'm afraid is `fgetcsv()` that can't parse that CSV correctly. Have you tried, before the query and without my code, to see the output of `print_r($line)`? Are fields splitted correctly?

Comment: @Reveller Ok, now you got it! You have just to eliminate double quotes using `trim($v, '"')` as I already showed you. Then, to eliminate index *jumps* and recompat the array, you just need `array_values()`. See my updated answer :)